# How to sign/add a public key in RHEL.?

Tags: ubuntu, rhel

I am trying to add a public key from Fusion Forge for RHEL. In Ubuntu, we use `wget -O - http://fusionforge.fusionforge.org/deb/B998DC6C.asc | apt-key add` to add a key. What is the command in RHEL for the same action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download and import the key in one step like you are doing above:

```
rpm --import http://fusionforge.fusionforge.org/deb/B998DC6C.asc
```

Check the documentation here for more info: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network/5.0.0/html/Client_Configuration_Guide/ch-gpg-keys.html

Comment: Hi Matt, Now I am geeting "Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe)" error. Can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: @ParuchuriSumi Yeah I overcomplicated it. Check the updated answer.